# jquery form with dialog ( issue with the if else loop in jquery)

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Hi have a form to submit with the help of jquery plugin "openid".now every thing works fine when i click on google_button but when i click on aol it will open dialog and will submit the form (when form.submit with return false is commented out) . when i remove the comments the aol will work fine with only aol dialog getting open and form not getting submitted but google form will also will not be submitted in that case.

Please help me out

================================================================================

```
<form action="example.php" method="post" >   
<input type="image" src="images/google_button.png" id='https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id' class="google"/> 
          <input type="image" src="images/AOL_button.png" id='http://openid.aol.com/' class='aol' />
</form>
```

================================================================================

```
 <script type="text/javascript">  
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form').openid(); 
      })
    </script>
```

================================================================================

```
(function($){
  $.fn.openid = function() {
    $('input').click(function(e){
      var provider = $(this).attr('class');
     if (provider == 'aol') {
        $("#dialog").dialog();
         /*$('form').submit(function(){
             return false;   
    })*/
     }
     else{
      var provider_url = $(this).attr('id');  //get id
      var myinput = $('<input type="hidden" name="provider_url"/>').val(provider_url);
      $('form').append(myinput);
      $('form').submit();
    }  
    })
  }
})(jQuery);
```

===============================================================================

Answer (score 0):

Try to send the form after `if else` construction.

Comment: i tried this but still the dialog opens but it closes automatically and form gets submitted  (function($){
  $.fn.openid = function() {
    $('input').click(function(e){
   var provider = $(this).attr('class');
  if (provider == 'aol') {
  $("#dialog").dialog(); 
   }
  else{
   var provider_url = $(this).attr('id');  //get id
      var myinput = $('<input type="hidden" name="provider_url"/>').val(provider_url);
       }  
  $('form').append(myinput);
      $('form').submit();
    })
  }
})(jQuery);

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($){
  $.fn.openid = function() {
    $('input').click(function(e){
      var provider = $(this).attr('class');
     if (provider == 'aol') {
        $("#dialog").dialog();
         /*$('form').submit(function(){
             return false;   
    })*/
  ***return false;***   //add return false in this section
     }
     else{
      var provider_url = $(this).attr('id');  //get id
      var myinput = $('<input type="hidden" name="provider_url"/>').val(provider_url);
      $('form').append(myinput);
      $('form').submit();
    }  
    })
  }
})(jQuery);
```